# Can I safely copy vector<array>?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, memcpy

I have a `vector<array<float,3>>` to use as a list of 3D Coordinates for my rendering.
Can I simply use memcpy with `sizeof(array<float,3>) * vector.size()` as the `count` argument?
Is the memory of vector safe to copy?

€dit: Here is a snippet of my code.
My question is a bit incorrectly phrased now.

```
vector<array<float,3>> vertexPositions;
//read VertexPositions, one line represents a vertex position and put them into vertexPositions with push_back();

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
//initialize Buffer Description;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA bufferInitialData;
bufferInitialData.pSysMem = vertexPositions.data(); //pSysMem is a void* and expects a sequence of floats
```

`pSysMem` is simply a `void*` and the structure has an additional size parameter that i set as `sizeof(array<float,3>) * vector.size()`

Comment: If you are using C++, don't use `memcpy`. `std::vector` has its own copy ctor. Please post minimal example of your code

Comment: I want the floats to be tightly packed (since they will be sent to the GPU), does this allow me to do that?

Comment: Please clarify _where_ you want to copy the data. I suspect you want to copy the data of the vector to a c-style array to use as buffer or something like this.

Comment: I have added example code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the memory of vector safe to copy?

Yes, a vector doesn't do anything special here, and elements will be packed the same as they would be for an array. You can see this easily because say `data()` returns a pointer that can be access as an array (for `[0]` up to `[myvec.size() - 1]`) until an operation is performed that invalidates that return (e.g. destroying or resizing the vector).

> I want the floats to be tightly packed (since they will be sent to the GPU), does this allow me to do that?

As such this basically means make sure the type you store *in the vector* meets the requirements. (e.g. that you actually want a 3-float RGB format, and not one of the integer formats or a RGBA or RGBX 4-element format). Depending on the API you use, you can probably even give it the vector data directly, without copying to a separate array (e.g. [`ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11device-createbuffer) takes a `pInitialData` and if you store the right type in the vector, you can just set `pSysMem` to be `myvector.data()`).

Comment: Thank you very much, that clears things up for me :)

Answer (score 4):

`array<float,3>` is trivially copyable, `vector.data()` is a contiguous block, yes it is safe to `memcpy`, but I'd consider it bad practice, I hope you have a good reason to not pass a pointer, copy the vector instead of the raw data or use `std::copy` instead.

To check if types are trivially copyable you can use [std::is_trivially_copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `std::array<float, 3> *` like the start of a `float[][3]`. You don't have one of those from taking the address of the vector.

```
std::vector<std::array<float,3>> vertexPositions;
//read VertexPositions, one line represents a vertex position and put them into vertexPositions with push_back();

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
//initialize Buffer Description;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA bufferInitialData;
bufferInitialData.pSysMem = static_cast<void *>(vertexPositions.data()); //pSysMem is a void* and expects a sequence of floats
```

Comment: I noticed that, too and edited my question so it uses `.data()` :)